# How to input a new line character while the execution of input() method in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, io

I would like to input a new line (a.k.a. line feed) character while the execution of `input()` method in Python 3. The character must be deletable (able to delete), but not like `sys.stdin.readlines()` (because the character there is not deletable). And I would like to stop the inputting by an exception (i.e. `KeyboardInterrupt`).

Can I do it? If so, how?

Comment: Hi @Chen, welcome to stackoverflow. I know my Python and the ins and outs of line formats, but I _cannot_ figure out what you are talking about. Can you describe what you are really trying to accomplish, i.e. the problem you are trying to solve with the deletable newlines and all that?

Comment: Newlines are managed by the terminal or whatever it is that your Python is running in, and yes they are special. To back up past a newline you need to do some extra work, and the details will depend on your operating system and on how you call your Python script.

Comment: I mean, the character must be deletable, for example: When I type “`foo` enter `bar`” and press backspace for 6 times, the result on the console is “`f`”, but not “`foo`” with a newline.

Comment: yeah, that's not up to Python, read my second comment.

Answer (score 0):

You loop your input indefinitely until you catch a keyboard interupt with the try except part. If you want to delete the newline anyway you can also directly forego adding it to string.

```
string = ''
try:
    while True:
        string += input()
        string += '\n' # optional
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(string)
```

Comment: I mean, the character must be deletable, for example:  
When I type “`foo` enter `bar`” and press backspace for 6 times, the result is “`f`”, but not “`foo`” with a newline.

Comment: @Chen-Y0y0 you can replace the \n with whatever you want. I dont think you can backspace through python inputs. You can either have a certain pattern a user needs to input for a backpace or its gonna be limited to one line

Comment: @Chen-Y0y0 That's not something you can do by reading from a stream alone; you need some sort of editor to construct the value that gets seen by Python. Take a look at the `readline` module.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a multiline application that is a complex problem to tackle because of how a command prompt works. I'd recommend you to look at [this](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/full_screen_apps.html) to create a fullscreen UI which might be what you need.

Otherwise, I can only think of making an event listener which reprints all the lines of your "editor" every time a keystroke happens, while it stores all the content of that "editor" in a string, and runs in a while-loop with a KeyboardInterrupt exception handler. Eg. say you press `a` `[enter]` `a` `[delete]` `[delete]` it will print 1+2+2+2+1 lines. I'm not saying this is the only solution, or the best, but would be a way to tackle it. I have done this kind of UI for a personal project but on fullscreen (printing a fixed number of lines every time) to update different parts of the prompt